# Open different activities from listview

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

I would like to open an activity for each of my listview items. Done some research around onitemclickListener but don't know quite how to fit in with my current code.

My activities are called:

1. BhutanInfo.java
2. ColumbiaInfo.java

My listview is set up in an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="country_names">
    <item>Bhutan</item>
    <item>Colombia</item>
</string-array>
<array name="country_icons">
    <item>@drawable/bhutan</item>
    <item>@drawable/colombia</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

In my class file I have the following:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
Resources res = ctx.getResources();

String[] options = res.getStringArray(R.array.country_names);
TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.country_icons);

setListAdapter(new ImageAndTextAdapter(ctx, R.layout.main_list_item, options, icons));
}
```

I also have another class which sets the adapter.

```
public class ImageAndTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private String[] mStrings;
private TypedArray mIcons;

private int mViewResourceId;

public ImageAndTextAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
        String[] strings, TypedArray icons) {
    super(ctx, viewResourceId, strings);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mStrings = strings;
    mIcons = icons;

    mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mStrings.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mStrings[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
    iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));

    TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_text);
    tv.setText(mStrings[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: depending on position pass the activity.. get position value ..if(position==0) pass to BhutanInfo.java .. if(position==1) pass to columbiaInfo.java

Comment: see this link it might help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134590/setlistadapter-problem-i-dont-know-how-this-works-at-all

Comment: Hi @Giridharan I tried coding based on position: protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
String openClass = classNames[position];  But this does not work either
try{
 Class selected = Class.forName("com.shaadcorp.countries." + openClass);
 Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
 startActivity(selectedIntent);
}catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
 e.printStackTrace()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement onclicklistener for listView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887378/how-to-implement-onclicklistener-for-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you had only two items means you can redirect the activity based on the position and you can perform this way

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String str = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Log.e("Clicked Value is", str);

            if(str.equals("<Your Class Name>")){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        FirstActivity.class);
            }else{

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Second.class);

            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I tried to put this in but I don't think I have done correctly, getting errors...Also I will eventually have more than 2 activities

Comment: @Mustafa: you can use any one way from the above, ie you need to check using list position or class name. If i found any better solution i will let you know. can you post what error you faced using the above code?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you used custom adapter, i am right.

so you can manage click listener in custom adapter,

if you don't want this scenario, then you have to

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in you custom list row in xml file, and then call then listview onclick listener it will work.

Answer (score 0):

in your `ActivityClass`, have the `listView` implement the `onItemClickListener`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        String value = options[position];

        if(value.equals("Bhutan")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, BhutanInfo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(value.equals("Columbia")){
             intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ColumbiaInfo.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

P.S: Ensure that `BhutanInfo` and `ColumbiaInfo` are extending `Activity`.
And in the row layout inflating the `listview` set `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to `false` for all the elements in it.