# How to implement onclicklistener for listView

Tags: java, android

I have an activity (MainActivity) which calls on a 2nd Activity (ImageAndTextAdapter) to display a listview.
I want to be able to click on each list item to open a new activity.  However I do not know how to implement the setOnItemClickListener function correctly.  I have tried many different ways.  Any help will be appreciated.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
Resources res = ctx.getResources();

String[] options = res.getStringArray(R.array.country_names);
TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.country_icons);

setListAdapter(new ImageAndTextAdapter(ctx, R.layout.main_list_item, options, icons));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;}


    }
```

ImageAndTextAdapter.java:

```
public class ImageAndTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private String[] mStrings;
private TypedArray mIcons;

private int mViewResourceId;

public ImageAndTextAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
    String[] strings, TypedArray icons) {
super(ctx, viewResourceId, strings);

mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

mStrings = strings;
mIcons = icons;

mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return mStrings.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
return mStrings[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));

TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_text);
tv.setText(mStrings[position]);

return convertView;
}
}
```

XML File:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="country_names">
    <item>Columbia</item>
    <item>Peru</item>
    <item>Argentina</item>
 </string-array>
<array name="country_icons">
    <item>@drawable/Columbia</item>
    <item>@drawable/Peru</item>
    <item>@drawable/Argentina</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onCreate() method, after `setListAdapter(new ImageAndTextAdapter(ctx, R.layout.main_list_item, options, icons));`, use:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // Handle your click here as you want

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for this.  I tried handling teh click like this: Class selected = Class.forName("com.shaadcorp.countries." + openClass);
 Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
 startActivity(selectedIntent);
}catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
 e.printStackTrace(); but getting errors,  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the name of the Activity you want to start when clicking an item?

Comment: I have 3 different activities: columbiainfo.java, peruinfo.java, argentinainfo.java

Comment: Then do this inside `onItemClick()`:

`Intent activityIntent;

if(position ==0){
    activityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ColumbiaInfo.class);
}

else if(position ==1){
    activityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PeruInfo.class);
}
else{
 activityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ArgentinaInfo.class);
}

startActivity(activityIntent);`